# Generics syntax: classes versus primitive data types

Tags: java, generics, primitive-types

Why does this one does not work:

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<int>>
```

where this one does:

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>
```

???

Comment: Please correct the typo in your question. syntx -> syntax, I haven't yet enough reputation to do so.

Comment: On this site, you have to accept an answer by clicking on the tick, so he becomes green.

Answer (score 7):

Because Java can only use classes (and not primitive types) and arrays (also arrays for primitives) for generics (between `<` and `>`).

```
List<Integer> list;
```

That is also a reason why there are wrapper classes for primitive types:

```
int -> Integer
boolean -> Boolean
double -> Double
byte -> Byte
etc...
```

Comment: I agree, but recently in interview, I was asked to write a generic class which can take primitive as well as object? I was not able to answer that question. I was wonder is the question valid at first place.

Comment: Maybe the interviewer was looking for `public MyClass<T extends Number>` ? This wouldn't work for Booleans.

Answer (score 1):

The argument in the `<>` must be an object because those classes can only hold objects.

`int` is a primitive type, where as `Integer` is simply a wrapper class for that type, so `Integer` is the one that will work.

Comment: yes i got it :) i thoght it does work for LinkedList<int> so it made me crazy ' just got confused with C++.

Answer (score 0):

becuase the definition is `LinkedList< T >` and only `Object` can be here `< T >` .

`int` is primitive type so `LinkedList< int > - compile error` 
`Integer` is object `LinkedList < Integer > - right one`